# How to redirect user to another Url from MVC Custom Router Handler?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, handler, iroutehandler

I am working with CustomMvcRouterHandler, Based on some logic I just want to redirect user  to another Url from CustomHandler.

```
public class CustomMvcRouterHandler : IRouteHandler
{

    public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        if (requestContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            if (logic is true)
            {
                string OrginalUrl = "/Home/AboutUs";
                // redirect Url = "/Home/CompanyProfile";
                return new MvcHandler(requestContext);
            }

        }

        return new MvcHandler(requestContext);
    }
}
```

**How to redirect user to "Home/CompanyProfile" from CustomRouterHandler ?**

Answer (score 1):

You can use underlying ASP.NET Response object to redirect user to another URL.

```
requestContext.Response.Redirect("/Home/CompanyProfile");
requestContext.Response.End();
```

It will send redirect response to the browser and end HTTP request processing.

Comment: Not possible. It cause "Redirect loop" error. I am using ASP.NET MVC (Front Controller) not Classic ASP.NET / ASP.NET (Page Controller)

Comment: Check /Home/CompanyProfile directly - it should not cause redirect to itself. Raw redirect works in MVC (I used it in version 3 and 4).

Comment: I think you miss  the line `return new MvcHandler(requestContext);`. and I am using it within Custom Handler.

Comment: creates redirect loop

Comment: This works: `requestContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("/Home/CompanyProfile");` I suspect the redirect error is due to another routing issue. Try redirecting to a static page to test: `requestContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("/test.html");`